# vlookup function between 2 files and append matches at EOL

Tags: awk, vlookup, text-processing

Need to vlookup from two different files having multiple entries:

cat file1.csv

```
aaaaaaa;24/09/2018;06/09/2018;1;89876768
bbbbbbb;15/09/2018;03/09/2018;2;76958489
ccccccc;10/09/2018;28/08/2018;3;57848472
ddddddd;22/09/2018;08/09/2018;4;17929730
eeeeeee;19/09/2018;30/08/2018;5;18393770
```

cat file2.csv

```
20180901;abc;1
20180901;sdf;2
20180904;jhh;2
20180905;skf;3
20180911;asf;2
20180923;ghf;4
20180925;asb;4
20180918;mnj;3
```

In addition for file1.csv, the fourth column is the identifier of the third colunm into file2.csv.

Output required is:

```
aaaaaaa;24/09/2018;06/09/18;1;89876768;20180901
bbbbbbb;15/09/2018;03/09/18;2;76958489;20180901;20180904;20180911
ccccccc;10/09/2018;28/08/18;3;57848472;20180905;20180918
ddddddd;22/09/2018;08/09/18;4;17929730;20180923;20180925
eeeeeee;19/09/2018;30/08/18;5;18393770;unknown
```

Comment: it is always recommended that you show us your effort too in your post which you have put in order to solve your problem. Then give it sometime and select 1 answer as correct answer out of all answers too to close the thread completely.

Comment: Sure, I'll keep this in mind for the next time. Thanks a lot.  My code was: awk -F "\"*;\"*" -vOFS=';' 'NR==FNR { a[$4] = $1 OFS; next }
     $3 in a { a[$1] = a[$1] (a[$1] ~ /;$/? "" : ";") $4 }
     END {
         for (i in a) print i, a[i] (a[i] ~ /;$/? "Not_Available" : "")
     }' OFS=';' file1.csv file2.csv

Comment: Sure, you could update your post with efforts ideally that should be the case, comments are not meant for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}FNR==NR{a[$NF]=a[$NF]?a[$NF] OFS $1:$1;next} {print ($4 in a)?$0 OFS a[$4]:$0 OFS "unknown"}' file2.csv  file1.csv
```

Output will be as follows.

```
aaaaaaa;24/09/2018;06/09/2018;1;89876768;20180901
bbbbbbb;15/09/2018;03/09/2018;2;76958489;20180901;20180904;20180911
ccccccc;10/09/2018;28/08/2018;3;57848472;20180905;20180918
ddddddd;22/09/2018;08/09/2018;4;17929730;20180923;20180925
eeeeeee;19/09/2018;30/08/2018;5;18393770;unknown
```

***Explanation of code:***

```
awk '
BEGIN{                                              ##Starting BEGIN section for awk here.
  FS=OFS=";"                                        ##Setting values for FS and OFS as semi colon.
}                                                   ##Closing block for BEGIN section here.
FNR==NR{                                            ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file named file2.csv is being read.
  a[$NF]=a[$NF]?a[$NF] OFS $1:$1                    ##Creating an array named a whose index is $NF and value is $1 and concatenating its own value with same index.
  next                                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                                   ##Closing block for FNR==NR condition here.
{
  print ($4 in a)?$0 OFS a[$4]:$0 OFS "unknown"     ##These statements will execute when 2nd Input_file is being read and printing value of $0 with condition if $4 is present in array a then concatenate its value with current line else concatenate unknown with it.
}' file2.csv  file1.csv                             ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 great man! It's working fine. Many thanks for your answer and explanation.